# Set value element to a other page called by window.open()

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to implement this case, I really appreciate your help.

**UPDATE :**

***page1.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body >
<form>  
    filled value : <input type="text" id="one">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

***page2.html***

```
<form>
    <input type="button" onclick='go();' value='call_page1'/>
</form>
```

*First attempt : page1 shows up, but value is not set*

```
 <script>
 function go(){
          var newWindow;
             newWindow= window.open('page1.html', 'form', 'width=400,height=350');
         newWindow.document.getElemetById('one').value='xxx';

}
   </script>
```

*Second attempt : page1 is not even shown up*

```
     <script>
    function go(){

     var detailsWindow;
        detailsWindow = window.open('page1.html', 'form', 'width=400,height=350');

        detailsWindow.onload = function{
    document.getElementById('one').value='test';
    }
    }
<script>
```

Question : setting `value`' value to `page1.html`, when it's called in `page2.html`?

Or if there's an alternative (but please take it easy on me, i'm just learning this stuff ). `I don't use JQuery`, if there's something unclear, i'm happy to hear it.

regard.

Comment: Scripts between windows is doable though I think there are better ways to handle this. Are you simply trying to initialize the input on `page1.html` when it's opened in a window by `page2.html`?

Comment: @MariM, exactly, but in my case i have to set it up from page2.html, this is   confusing me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all javascript is case sensetive, and `n` is missing. so replace `getElemetByID` with `getElementById`.

Second is that the code executes immediately and doesn't wait the page to load. You must wrap your code in `window.onload` :

```
newWindow.onload = function(){
     newWindow.document.getElementById('one').value='xxx';
}
```

there's 3 bugs in the update:

1. `function` in `detailsWindow.onload = function` must be declared with `detailsWindow.onload = function()` to work.
2. your end script is must be replaced from `<script>` to `</script>`
3. you are missing `detailsWindow` in `document.getElementById('one').value = 'test';` it must be `detailsWindow.document.getElementById('one').value = 'test';`

Comment: you forgot to add `detailsWindow ` before `document.getElementById('one')`. and make sure that page2 contains iframe with name set to `form`.

Comment: can you post your full page2 html page

Comment: Ok, it's working now..., thank you so much for "onload ()" clue you gave, that's the key,actually my 'second attem (which is your answer)' is working just fine, I just forget to close the the second window , so in the second call there's nothing shows up.

Answer (score 4):

// page1.html

```
<script>
var newWindow = window.open('page2.html', 'formUntukUpdate', 'width=400,height=350');
newWindow.onload = function(){
    newWindow.document.getElementById('one').value = 'ok 2';
};
</script>
```

// page2.html

```
<input type="text"  id="one" value="ok" />
```