# Javascript Callback function not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Here I am trying to achieve callback function by passing function to another.In below example onclick button calling `invoke_reporting` first parameter textdata is having some data in text format.
Also passing callback but not getting called.

```
function invoke_reporting(textdata,callback) {

    window.open("http://192.168.17.109/TestCopy_Report1/templates/ct-scan-head");

    if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {

        callback(textdata);
    }
}

function callback(finaldata){
    alertify("callback function");
    document.getElementById("post-data").innerHTML = finaldata;

    window.opener.document.getElementById('post-data').value = finaldata;
}
```

And in the newly opened window I want to assign textdata value into this new opened window textarea.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<form id="report">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="post-data">Report Data(Text Format):</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <textarea class="form-control" rows="20" id="post-data" name="post-data"></textarea>
       </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="launch" id="launch" onclick="invoke_reporting(document.getElementById('post-data').value)">Launch</button>
     </div>
   </div>

</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you invoking the functions with? I don't see any invocations in your current code

Comment: Getting text area data onclick invoking_report. This data I want to show in the newly opened window using callback functions.

Comment: Please post the actual code so we can look at it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are not passing the callback function to the `invoke_reporting` function

change this

```
<div class="col-sm-6"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="launch" id="launch" onclick="invoke_reporting(document.getElementById('post-data').value)">Launch</button>
```

to

```
<div class="col-sm-6"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="launch" id="launch" onclick="invoke_reporting(document.getElementById('post-data').value,callback)">Launch</button>
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/bk5pac3f/)

hope this helps.

EDIT

To set value in the textarea of newly opened window  try the following code.

```
function invoke_reporting(textdata,callback) {

 var newwindow =    window.open("http://192.168.17.109/TestCopy_Report1/templates/ct-scan-head");

    if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {

        callback(textdata,newwindow);
    }
}

function callback(finaldata,newwindow){
    alertify("callback function");
    newwindow.onload = function(){
    newwindow.document.getElementById('post-data').value = finaldata;
   };
}
```

i got answer from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083502/set-value-element-to-a-other-page-called-by-window-open)

Comment: Callback works fine thank you. How can I assign that data into newly opened windw textarea.