# How to populate data and control when window.open

Tags: javascript

For example right, Google website. 
I had found that Search textbox is name=q and Search button is name=btnK.
I am managed to open the browser by using the

```
var wdw = window.open(url, "_blank");
```

But I can't populate the data into the textbox as well as trigger the button.
I have tried like

```
wdw.document.getElementsByName("q").value = "something";
```

But still failed, please kindly advise. Thanks

**2nd Attempt**

```
var vWindow = window.open(GOOGLE_SITE, "_blank");
            vWindow.onload = function() {
                vWindow.document.getElementsByName("q").value = "Find ABC";

            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set value element to a other page called by window.open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083502/set-value-element-to-a-other-page-called-by-window-open)

Comment: you should try load event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

Comment: you need to use the `wdn.onload` event

Comment: No. It wont work also. I will post the code under 2nd attempt

Comment: You do know if you want to search google you can just use the querystring right? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=search

Comment: So `window.open("google.co.uk/search?q=Find+ABC", "_blank");` would basically do what you need to do

Comment: Hi Liam. Indeed, basically google is just part of my example/experience of my goal. My goal is that I can control the properties (eg: textbox, label, button, etc) when a new webpage is load/prompt.

Comment: You can only do that if you open a page from the same origin (protocol, domain and port) - the Same Origin Policy prevents you from interacting with content from a different origin with JavaScript.

Comment: Oh. So there is no way to do so? Due to policy thingy and the origin thingy.

Answer (score 0):

```
You meet the problem of security. Protocol, domain, etc

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Another approach:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="openNewWindow()">Open window</button>

<script>
function openNewWindow() {

    // Open new window
    var newWindow = window.open("", "My New Window", "width=500,height=500");

    newWindow.document.write("<p>My New Widown</p>");
    newWindow.document.write("<input type='text' id='name' />");
    newWindow.document.write("<button id='ok'>OK</button>");

    // populate the data into the textbox
    newWindow.document.getElementById('name').value = "Test";

    // Listen button click event
    var btn = newWindow.document.getElementById('ok');
    btn.addEventListener('click', clickOk);
}


function clickOk(){
    console.log("Ok Click");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```